# PostgreSQL/Pandas insert sparse array containing null/np.nan/empty values

Tags: sql, postgresql, pandas, numpy, psycopg2

I want to insert an array that contains empty values created from Pandas in Python, and these empty values default to np.nan in Pandas dataframe. I don't want them to be 'NaN' in my PostgreSQL database, I want my PostgreSQL arrays to contain empty values like this: `'{123,24,,23}'` so they are not counted in my aggregate functions like calculating the mean or standard deviation across indices. I am not sure if it is possible to have sparse arrays in PostgreSQL. There won't be a lot of sparse arrays in my dataset, I am just testing this for edge case purposes.

My table schema:

```
create_table = '''
            CREATE TABLE {t} (
                patient_id VARCHAR[20] PRIMARY KEY,
                gene_expression double precision []
            );
        '''
```

The relevant Python code (I don't know how to write the proper SQL code here). Here I converted the array into a string, because Python arrays cannot be sparse:

```
df = df.fillna('')
NCI = [1]
MCI = [2,3]
AD = [4,5]
other = [6]

insert_sql = '''
                INSERT INTO {t} (patient_id, gene_expression)
                VALUES (%s,%s);
            '''
cur = psql_conn.cursor()

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    arr = row[2:].tolist()
    postgres_arr = ','.join(map(str, arr))
    if row['DIAGNOSIS'].isdigit():
        if int(row['DIAGNOSIS']) in NCI:
            cur.execute(insert_sql.format(t='nci'), (row['PATIENT_ID'], postgres_arr,))

        elif int(row['DIAGNOSIS']) in MCI:
            cur.execute(insert_sql.format(t='mci'), (row['PATIENT_ID'], postgres_arr,))

        elif int(row['DIAGNOSIS']) in AD:
            cur.execute(insert_sql.format(t='ad'), (row['PATIENT_ID'], postgres_arr,))

        elif int(row['DIAGNOSIS']) in other:
            cur.execute(insert_sql.format(t='other'), (row['PATIENT_ID'], postgres_arr,))

    elif row['DIAGNOSIS'] == '':
        cur.execute(insert_sql.format(t='na'), (row['PATIENT_ID'], postgres_arr,))

    else:
        print('ERROR: unknown diagnosis {d}.'.format(d=diagnosis))

psql_conn.commit()
cur.close()
```

My Error:

```
psycopg2.DataError: malformed array literal: "{2.0,2.4,}"
LINE 3:                     VALUES ('X100_120417','{2.0,2.4,}');
                                                  ^
DETAIL:  Unexpected "}" character.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few hours of trial and error:

Load this Pandas dataframe **df** from some CSV file:

```
+----+-------+--------------+
| id | stuff |    array     |
+----+-------+--------------+
|  0 | a     | {1,2,3}      |
|  1 | b     | {1,np.nan,3} |
|  2 | 45    | {np.nan,4,2} |
+----+-------+--------------+
```

process in pandas using:

```
df = df.fillna('NULL')
insert_sql = '''
                INSERT INTO {t} (patient_id, gene_expression)
                VALUES (%s,%s);
            '''

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    arr = row[2:].tolist()
    postgres_arr = '{' + ','.join(map(str,arr)) + '}'
    cur.execute(insert_sql.format(t='my_table'), (row['id'], postgres_arr,))
```

My main issue was recognizing that string literal 'NULL' automatically translate to PostgreSQL NULL keyword, which is ignored in calculations and results of aggregate functions return a value as if the NULL values are not there, versus NaN keyword where every operation with it results in NaN.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a column with max length, use bracket, not square brackets. change `VARCHAR[20]` to `VARCHAR(20)` in create table statement. Otherwise first `%s` is expected to be array and it is varchar. Here is sample - mind that patient_id is created as array, not varchar...

```
t=# CREATE TABLE so23 (
                patient_id VARCHAR[20] PRIMARY KEY,
                gene_expression double precision []
            );
CREATE TABLE
t=# \d+ so23
                                    Table "public.so23"
     Column      |        Type         | Modifiers | Storage  | Stats target | Description
-----------------+---------------------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------
 patient_id      | character varying[] | not null  | extended |              |
 gene_expression | double precision[]  |           | extended |              |
Indexes:
    "so23_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (patient_id)
```

Comment: thanks that was a typo, how would you insert NULL instead of 'nan' in the array? Because all operations with 'nan' results in 'nan', but I want to ignore 'nan' values.